# React component not setting state

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component to represent a task list, called `<Tasks>` that looks like this:

```
var Tasks = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            tasks: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setState({
            tasks: this.props.tasks
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var tasks = this.state.tasks.map(function (task) {
            return (
                <Task key={task.id} description={task.description} completed={task.completed} />
            );
        });
        return (
            <table className="table table-tasks">
                <tbody>
                    {tasks}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

But `this.state.tasks` is not being set. Using the React inspector for Chrome, I can see `this.props.tasks` is an array of two objects (expected), but `this.state.tasks` is an empty array. So it seems the `setState` call in my `componentDidMount` method isn’t actually setting the state.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works just fine when I copied it and tried it myself, so you have to look for the problem elsewhere. There is nothing wrong with the example provided.

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep copy of "tasks" in state? (Actually, it's not even copied). This brings more harm than good...

Comment: @Andreyco Well my component represents a list of tasks that can be added, edited, or removed, so that’s manipulating the tasks’ state, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can access `props` in `getInitialState()`. No idea where I’ve picked up the convention of setting state in `componentDidUpdate()`, so now I’m just doing:

```
var Tasks = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        this.setState({
            tasks: this.props.tasks
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var tasks = this.state.tasks.map(function (task) {
            return (
                <Task key={task.id} description={task.description} completed={task.completed} />
            );
        });
        return (
            <table className="table table-tasks">
                <tbody>
                    {tasks}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

Thanks to Jack Franklin for the [tip](https://twitter.com/Jack_Franklin/status/687989521607208960)!